# Determine total bytes written to disk on Windows

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a *Windows built-in* way to determine the total amount of data written to a disk/partition on Windows for a period of time to estimate the necessary TBW for a SSD.

There are many options (e.g. Task Manager) or tools (e.g. Process Explorer) to get process specific data but as far as I researched they doesn't take account of 
short-lived processes like triggered copy jobs. The built in Performance Monitor also doesn't seem to provide those values I'm looking for.

I've found the tool DiskCountersView (nirSoft) which shows you TBR/TBW since the last reboot of Windows but I don't know if I can trust the values as long as I don't know how they are collected.

**Update**

After asking Nir how DiskCountersView gathers the values he gave me a hint regarding IOCTL (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-ioctl_disk_performance).

See also (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450157/how-to-get-global-windows-i-o-statistics).

After all it seems that Windows still hasn't a built-in command to get those values and you have to deal with the API.

Anyway, now I know how the tool works I guess I can trust the results that fit my needs.

Comment: So what's actually your question? It seems like you got all the information you need, ruled out some tools and trust the ones you're left with.

Comment: No, I don't have all the information. But I agree with your annotation that I didn't formulate my initial intension correctly.

Answer (score 5):

DiskCountersView gets its data from Windows and not from the
[S.M.A.R.T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) data of the disk.

S.M.A.R.T. attributes are maintained by the firmware of the disk,
not by Windows, and pertain for the entire lifetime of the disk.

The nirsoft utility to use is
[DiskSmartView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/disk_smart_view.html)
which retrieves the S.M.A.R.T information,
if you wish to verify the information from DiskCountersView,

Many other free tools may be found in the article
[Best Free Hard Drive Health Monitoring and Diagnostic Programs](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-disk-health-monitoring-utility.htm).

The S.M.A.R.T attributes you are most interested in are probably:

> **241 - Total LBAs Written**: The total number of 512-byte sectors written
>   during the entire lifetime of the device.
>
> **242 - Total LBAs Read**: The total number of 512-byte sectors read
>   during the entire lifetime of the device.

Comment: I can't belive that this tool get's the information from S.M.A.R.T. values (or not only). At least not for HDDs because mostly they don't provide this values but the tools still shows I/O in bytes (more or less) correctly. Further it's not capable to show any information from volumes that reside on hw raid devices.

Comment: Actually you are right and there is one red flag in the description as regarding the 'Reset All Counter Values' option. I changed my answer.

Comment: @harrymc why is DiskSmartView showing nothing for my SSDs, NVMEs and HDDs? I tried running it from cli or GUI, nothing. Empty report.

Comment: @avia: Try another utility, for example [speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy). If this is still happening, you could post the question on our site.

Comment: @harrymc really appreciate your advice, speccy worked for me thanks!

Comment: ugh, i was hoping for a *Windows built in way* as the question specifies, now that my pre-existing `smartctl` now refuses to function after being virtualized in Hyper-V.